# Find $ \limsup([0,{\cos^{2}}(n)]) $ and $ \liminf([0,{\cos^{2}}(n)]) $.

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I am interested in finding the quantities $ \displaystyle \limsup(A_{n}) $ and $ \displaystyle \liminf(A_{n}) $ for a sequence $ (A_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of sets of real numbers, where $ A_{n} = [0,{\cos^{2}}(n)] $ for every $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. My guess is that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup(A_{n}) = [0,1) \qquad \text{and} \qquad
\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf(A_{n}) = \{0\},
$$
but I cannot prove this since I am not aware of the distribution of the numbers $ {\cos^{2}}(n) $ within the interval $ [0,1] $. For example, is it true that any given $ x > 0 $ avoids infinitely many of the $ A_{n} $’s (which implies, of course, that $ \displaystyle \liminf(A_{n}) = \{0\} $)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the identity $ {\cos^{2}}(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} [1 + \cos(2 x)] $ would help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Berrick. Well, i have thought of this classic identity but again I got myself to the way the cos(2n) 's are distributed on [-1,1], which is easier of course tha before, but, again, not clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well known that the numbers $e^{2in}$, $n\in{\mathbb N}$, are dense on the unit circle. It follows that the numbers
$$a_n:=\cos^2 n={1\over2}\bigl(1+{\rm Re}(e^{2in})\bigr)$$
are dense in the interval $[0,1]$. This immediately implies that your conjectures about $\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}A_n$ and $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}A_n$ are true.

Comment: I expected a density argument. Thanks a lot for the help!